# how can i access objects with in an array in ejs

Tags: node.js, ejs

I have a objects within an array and I need to loop through the objects. How can I achieve this inside an EJS template?

```
[{
    "show": "589c062d0d9c41040755519b",
    "date_range": [
        ["2017 Feb 28"]
    ],
    "ticketing": [{
        "2017 Feb 28": null
    }]
    }, {
        "show": "589b6d2710440e6d6399b1a8",
        "date_range": [
            ["2017 Feb 6"],
            ["2016 Dec 7"],
            ["2017 Feb 25"]
        ],
        "ticketing": [{
            "2017 Feb 6": null
        }, {
            "2016 Dec 7": null
        }, {
            "2017 Feb 25": null
        }]
    }
}]
```

Comment: my bad, i am passing as a JSON.stringify(data) which returning as a string , so that no way i'd loop it.

Comment: So is your problem resolved?

Comment: @nicovank yes problem resolved thanks.